# Why is my event on body called before event on specific element?

Tags: javascript, events, zurb-foundation-5

I have this code in my project which is using Foundation 5.5.3

```
$(function() {
  var $carsDropdown = $("#cars-dropdown");

  // Close cars dropdown when clicking outside of it or on close button
  $("body, #cars-dropdown .btn-close").click(function(ev) {
    if ($carsDropdown.hasClass("open")) {
      console.log("Dropdown is open");
      console.log("Closing dropdown.\n");
      Foundation.libs.dropdown.close($carsDropdown);
      // ev.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
      console.log("Dropdown is closed\n");
    }
  });
);
```

I am expecting this to close the div when I click on body and that works.
It also works perfectly when I click on .btn-close.

But when I click on element which should open and close the dropdown using foundation code, nothing happens.
Console output is this:

```
Dropdown is open.
Closing dropdown.
```

Just like when I click on `.btn-close`.

From this I am concluding that somehow event on `body` gets triggered before foundation event on button which should toggle the dropdown.
My event closes the dropdown and foundation code toggles it open.

How is it possible that body event is not triggered last? Aren't events supposed to bubble from inner most element to body tag last?

Now when I uncomment the `ev.stopPropagation()` line, everything works as expected. Click on body prevents propagation to some other element? How is this possible?

For testing please using this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZyRLp

Comment: @charlietfl - yes, but click on body should be called last. That's my question - why is ti called first.

Comment: It shouldn't work this way, maybe it comes from foundation. If I try to e.preventDefault, the toggle from foundation isn't prevented. It doesn't looks like it's classic event

Comment: @Nevosis - thanks tihs was helpful. You probably meant `ev.stopPropagation()`. I have edited the question to include this info.

Comment: because the click on the button fires first and than the click on the body fires second.

Comment: @epascarello - that's what should happen, but it seems like it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Their event listener is most likely delegated to document so you can add such functionality dynamically.

That is why you see the body event before class is added

Check the target and don't do anything if it is a `data-dropdown` element

```
$("body, #cars-dropdown .btn-close").click(function(e) {

  if (!$(e.target).closest('[data-dropdown]').length) {

    if ($carsDropdown.hasClass("open")) {
      console.log("Dropdown is open");
      console.log("Closing dropdown.\n");
      Foundation.libs.dropdown.close($carsDropdown);
    } else {
      console.log("Dropdown is closed\n");
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Foundation Dropdown button');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this already works if I uncomment the `ev.stopPropagation()` line.

Comment: ok so basically same bubbling issue, different approach. you are stopping it going up to document from body in the delegation on their button